# Kafka:Got invalid iterator state when running multiple inbound adapters

Tags: scala, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I just run a simple task using KAFKA by connecting 2 inbound adapters at same topic. It got following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Iterator is in failed state
at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:54)

It works fine with 1 inbound. I google it and found people has encountered this problem so far. But it seems that their solutions are not applicable in my case (below suggest to use a latest version, but I am using the latest one.)

[Consuming from Kafka failed Iterator is in failed state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046294/consuming-from-kafka-failed-iterator-is-in-failed-state)

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you guys!